# Tools in QGIS for cleaning polyline topology?

Tags: qgis, topology, dangle

Are there polyline topology cleaning tools in QGIS that perform same as ET Geowizard's "Renode Polylines" and "Clean Dangling Nodes" ?

https://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/ETGW12UG_WEB/etgw/Renode_Wizard.htm

https://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/cleanDanglingNodes.htm

Running ET GeoWiz's "Renode Polylines" followed by output polyline into ET GeoWiz's "Clean Dangling Nodes" (Dangling Tolerance = 10 Feet) - SNAP TO NEAREST POLYLINE works great, but would like to do the same in QGIS.

I have tried using GRASS v.clean (same as v.clean.advanced), but not getting correct outputs following instructions here: https://www.geodose.com/2017/10/how-to-clean-topology-error-in-qgis.html

Cleaning a driveways polyline layer with many topology errors is the task at hand.

Comment: In what way(s) was the output not "correct"?  I have found in my work that it is best to check geometry, then run v.clean to snap and break, and then input that to other tools like remove duplicates, then try to remove dangles in v.clean.  If that last step doesn't work perhaps you can recalculate lengths and select those at or under a tolerance for deletion.  Because all the outputs are temporary you can run a string of tools rather quickly and not have a mess of files to clean up.

Comment: If you can use postgis, there is the pgrouting extension.  That will allow you to node your network, create a topology, and identify isolated segments and dead ends.  There is also the topology extension, but I'm not sure if it handles the noding for you.

Comment: Following "Clean Topology Errors in Polyline Dataset" in https://www.geodose.com/2017/10/how-to-clean-topology-error-in-qgis.html  break, snap, rmdangle = 0, 5, 5. QGIS throws 3 different sets of errors as shown here: https://i.imgur.com/FPnTtYR.png  and produces an empty "cleaned" shp file.